# How can I convert a base64 string to a base64 PDF string?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, pdf, base64

I would appreciate if someone could shed light to a problem I'm having.

I'm using a .pdf viewer in AngularJS that from a base64 shows the document in a modal. This works well when the base64 is generated from a .pdf document.

This base64 is generated in the backend (Java) using the `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString()` function.

Is there a way to encode (it can be with JavaScript or Java) a different type of file (.jpeg, .png, .docx), to a base64 that represents that file but in .pdf format?

If my question is unclear, please feel free to correct me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File formats are defined at the source (i.e., a file is created as PDF, PNG, JPEG, etc.), and there is no way to view any file that is not a PDF in a PDF viewer without converting the original format to PDF.

**Edit**

If you are interested in converting the files to PDF, there are several open source libraries that can help. A common example is [Apache PDF Box](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), but there are also many other options out there.

Comment: So is the only solution to convert the file first to .pdf, and then convert that .pdf to a base64 string? (by using ´documents4j´ let's say?)

Comment: @Vitz I would say yes, unless you'd like to use other specific viewers for the file formats you are handling.

Comment: @Vitz Also, you don't necessarily need to convert your content to Base64 before streaming it to the client (i.e., your JavaScript code). If you set the correct `Content-Type` header in the response, you can stream any binary file AS-IS and the application server will take care of converting it to Base64. For example, if you store your PDF file in a `byte[] pdf` variable, you can stream it using `response.getOutputStream().write(pdf)`.